# Visual Studio 2015 crashes running asp.net mvc application - Duplicate type with name 'Microsoft.Web.Design'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2015

When I try debug a asp.net mvc application (just pressing F5) the Visual Studio 2015 crashes and restart. It shows the error message:

Duplicate type with name 'Microsoft.Web.Design' in assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Design.Web, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What version of MVC? Check config like `web.config` for duplicates? Maybe disable any extensions or disable/ uninstall nuget packages you have recently added?

Comment: Also does it happen when you create a new Solution? e.g. for every MVC app you open in Visual Studio - or just this one solution in particular?

Comment: The version is ASP.NET MVC 5, there is not none special extensions or packets recently added, just the regular visual studio updates. This happens with every MVC app, and also with a new solution.